# On click of same button open model and then submit form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please help me with this :

I have a form with a submit button . Now i want to open a modal window on click event of this button . In the modal i need to show a text box for inserting something in DB with 2 buttons : Cancel and Push . On click of push i want data to be inserted in the db and form to be submitted !!! 
Somehow i am unable to achieve this

```
<form action="post_data.php" method="post">
  <!-- some elements -->
  <input type ="submit" value = "Push data">    
</form>
```

I am using bootstrap-modal.js 
But the problem i am facing is my form points to x.php and now if I need to open a bootstrap model then i need to provide attributes : href="mymodal_id" and data-toggle="modal" for my submit button . If i do that my page does absolutely nothing :( :( 
Please Help 
Any help wil be appreciated . Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to use JavaScript to do this. There are many Frameworks which help you. I.e. jQuery+Bootstrap do a good job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `<a>` to trigger your modal:

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>
```

And then put your submit and cancel button inside that modal:

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Pushing to DB</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>You are going to push data</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Push data">Push data</button>
    </div>
</div>
```